How do astronauts feel in their stomach when they eat/drink something in space or microgravity?
Is it normal like on earth or there's a slight difference in digestion of food?
I think microgravity maybe playing role at little extent in digestion of food. and they have difficulty while gulping it. Any plausible answers will be appreciated.

There's a good example from that time when Coke and Pepsi did a full on advertisement war and had the astronauts do taste tests on the Space Shuttle. Turns out, carbonated beverages and microgravity don't mix well.

Any specific effect can you mention?

@Secret007 Bubbles don't rise in space, but they do merge and form larger bubbles, so the Pepsi can dispensed something more like a mouthful of cola foam than a drinkable product.  The Coke design was more evolved (they were the ones who proposed it and Pepsi was trying to catch up the whole time) and it actually more or less worked, but apparently the mouth feel still wasn't great.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Cola_Wars
